# I can't figure out how to turn on TestFlight beta testing

Tags: app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, I go into my app under Prerelease> Internal Testers. My tester status has been added but where there would normally be a switch for TestFlight it says, "To start testing, turn on TestFlight beta testing" I've looked this up in a google search and have come up with nothing really useful.

Answer (score 2):

The switch to activate TestFlight beta testing is currently in the "Builds" section under "Prerelease", on the right, above the list of your builds.
Here is a screenshot I just made. It is in german, but it should be the same in the english version.

[image: itunes connect]

Comment: I know. My problem is, where your red arrow is pointing, that part is missing. there isn't a switch to turn on "Betatests mit TestFlight?" this is what I see (I don't have photoshop on this computer yet).

Comment: I'm sure you already have checked this, but maybe you missed some point in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2).

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted the app for Beta Review? This is a crucial step, and if you don't, it will just not be available for beta testing. The review is not as stringent as the app store review, but is necessary.

Comment: I believe so. in Xcode I went to Products> Archive and submitted my app. In the end, it said, my app had been successfully submitted with a green circle and a green checkmark above it. Is this what you're talking about it? Does it take a few days to fully review it?

Comment: It is a two step process. You submit from Xcode to the App Store. That is step 1, and crucial.

But.. from there, this only means that you have a submitted build in your iTunesAccount. You can have as many up there as you want.

It is now up to you to decide to a) submit the build for App Review, or b) submit the build for Beta Review. These are distinct and independent steps.

Comment: Not sure exactly what went wrong but for some reason, everything is working and I did absolutely nothing different. It may have just been the beta version I was on.

Comment: You dont have to submit it for Beta Review if you are just inviting internal testers. You just need the three app icons and can leave the rest of the metadata unfilled. You do need to wait for the build to get beyond 'Processing' in iTunes Connect (under Prerelease->Builds) before the option for Betatest testflight appears.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed a bit since the last answer. Once you upload your TestFlight enabled build (and Apple has processed it):

1. Go to itunesconnect.apple.com and login
2. Select My Apps
3. Select the app you are trying to get to beta
4. Select TestFlight on the top menu
5. [optional] You may need to fill out Test Information and Save if you haven't done so before
6. Select Internal Testing or External Testing depending on your needs (internal doesn't require any Apple involvement, external does).
7. [optional] You may need to add users to your tester list
8. Select "Select Version to Test" and choose the correct version
9. Select "Start Testing"